# Issue with Nested family filtering by hidding & unhide the elements based on Specific parameter & its value

Tags: filtering, revit-api, forge, viewer

I am experiencing the problems of filtering for nested families on forge viewer . In Revit, for both nested family and top family we have check marked the shared parameter option. On forge viewer we are trying to filter the model elements based on parameter values assigned to elements (Let's say our **parameter Name: Layer; Value is XXXXX or YYYYY** for both top family & nested family) in Revit project. When we do the filtering on forge viewer, only the top family element gets filtered & gets hidden & the nested family element still its visible, not getting hidden. We found that the dbids of the nested family is not obtained by forge viewer, only top family dbids are obtained. Unchecking the shared parameter in nested & shared family treats the Revit family component as a single merged element but when we need to re-edit the family component in Revit for changing parameters, materials or to get in schedule, we need to check the shared parameter once again causing same problematic issue on forge viewer again.

On ACC(Autodesk Construction Cloud) we checked with edit filter our own custom p**roperty Layer with value XXXXXX or YYYYYY**, the filter works properly but on forge viewer its not working
Appreciate your help!!!

Thanks in advance!!!

We tried adding values to both the nested family and shared family. Did all the methods given on this website also. Nothing works.

Expecting to work : When we filter with XXXXX value the nested family (Note that here, top family = XXXXX, Nested family = YYYYYY) which has value YYYYY should be visible & the top family should be hidden; When we filter with YYYYYYY value, top family has XXXXX value need to be visible & the nested family should be hidden.

Please help!!!!